# Need a better explanation for try/catch/throw/throws exception handing in Java

Tags: java, exception

I am a little unsure about the difference between the try/catch, throw and throws in Java and every website seems to have an inhuman way of explaining it, I have tried the Oracle website but I just could not understand their explanation, is this correct?

**Try/catch**

With try catch, I want to try a piece of code and if something goes wrong do this.

**Throw**

With throw, I am throwing an error because I want to? 
So if I wanted to validate a users age, say all people over 20 and the user does not meet the requirements, I would throw an error?

**Throws**

With Throws I am throwing an error but something else handles the exception? Would this be another method/class?

Comment: 'throws' doesn't throw anything. it merely informs the calling methods/... that there might be an Exception thrown for which they may have to implement Exception handling, or throw it themselves in case it is thrown.  start here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: try/catch: ahndle the exception in the place where it occurs. throw: you can determine a program breaking situation and want to abort the program before it can go any further. Throws: indicates that a method can throw an exception which has to be handled elsewhere (mostly used to delegate server exceptions to the client)

Comment: @Stultuske I already did but I could not understand the terminology, I needed a much simplier less technical explanation first so I could then work from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try / Catch**

```
try
{
    // try to do some actions
}
catch(SomeExceptionType exception)
{
    // if the above actions throw a SomeExceptionType, do these actions
}
```

**Throw**

Correct. We're explicitly throwing an exception. You may do this if, for example, the caller of a method has violated your method's contract. Perhaps an argument cannot be negative.

In this situation, the best way to deal with this is to throw an exception which stops what we're doing and allows callers further up the stack to deal with the problem:

```
/** Do a thing. myInt must be positive */
void someMethod(Integer myInt)
{
    if (myInt < 0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't be negative");
    }
    // do something
}

void myCaller()
{
    someMethod( 1); // won't throw
    someMethod(-1); // will throw
}
```

**Throws**

`throws` is used as a keyword when dealing with [checked exceptions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Checked_Exceptions). It's a way of letting callers know what checked exceptions they can expect they may have to deal with.

Those methods can decide to deal with the problem (i.e. a try-catch) or can themselves declare the same exception type to be thrown to propagate the exception up to their caller (and so on and so on)

Comment: someMethod( 1); you have as explanation 'won't throw', but it won't run, since the first call throws an unhandled exception. Seeing as it is a question asked by someone who doesn't understand how the Exception handling works, and wants to learn specifically that, it might be a good thing to mention that.

Comment: @Stultuske True enough. I just reversed them because I'm lazy

Comment: @Michael Perfect that explained things perfectly!

Comment: @Ninja2k Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

You forget a important point : in Java all exceptions are not handled by the compiler in the same way.

The compiler ensures **only** that the checked exceptions be handled.
These exceptions don't inherit from `RuntimeException` but from `Exception` (directly or indirectly).

So whatever you throw in your code or a method of a third class declares throwing a checked exception, **you have to explicitly** handle it.

And there you have two ways :

- catching the exception
- letting the exception be propagated to the caller

`try/catch` addresses  the first way while specifying the `throws` modifier in the method declaration addresses the second.

For no `RunTimeException`s, you don't have this constraint as the compiler doesn't force you to handle it. You *may* handle them if you want to.